# Execute a where condition when search key is not null in Laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, where-clause

I would like to run where condition on a select query only when the search key is not empty. If the search key is empty skip that where condition. This is my code,

```
$users =  User::orderBy('id','asc')
            ->join('agents', 'users.id', '=', 'agents.user_id')
            ->select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.email')

            ->where('agents.category', 'like', '%'.$category.'%')

            ->orWhere('agents.location', 'like', '%'.$operation.'%')
            ->get();
```

In this query if the variable `$category` is empty no need to run that where condition. and `$operation` is null what where condition need to be skip. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with [tag:jquery].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following:

```
$users =  User::orderBy('id','asc')->join('agents', 'users.id', '=', 'agents.user_id')->select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.email');
if(!is_null($category)) {
$users =  $users->where('agents.category', 'like', '%'.$category.'%')->orWhere('agents.location', 'like', '%'.$operation.'%');
}
$users = $users->get();
```

or:

```
$users =  User::orderBy('id','asc')->join('agents', 'users.id', '=', 'agents.user_id')->select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.email')->where('agents.location', 'like', '%'.$operation.'%');
if(!is_null($category)) {
$users =  $users->orWhere('agents.category', 'like', '%'.$category.'%');
}
$users = $users->get();
```